# Can't find layout.xml

Tags: layout, rwd-theme, magento-connect, popup

I'm newbie with Magento.
I have installed an extension with Magento Connect, the extension page says:

In this free version the following code must be manuallly pasted at XML custom layout update:
       
      
    ﻿﻿

Actually I'm using RWD, I guess I have to past this code on layout.xml and I can't find it anywhere. Do I need to make this file myself?

Comment: Yes, you need a 'local.xml' file in your theme folder. In there you will need a layout tag. Read up on getting started with local.xml in themes to get you started.

Comment: Wolfir,please put this as answer and francessco,please accet this asnwer

Answer (score 2):

Adding comment as an answer to not leave this unanswered:

> Yes, you need a 'local.xml' file in your theme folder. In there you will need a layout tag. Read up on getting started with local.xml in themes to get you started.

*– Henry's Cat Jun 8 '15 at 10:12*